# Get the shipping zone for specific city, state and postal code in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

This is what I'm doing,
I have added 3 shipping zone at the dashboard:

1. Shipping zone 1 "2 cities"
2. shipping zone 2 "12 city"
3. shipping zone 3 "rest of the world"

And, I want to show specific messages related to the delivery process at the checkout page, but I couldn't get in which zone the customer address is.

What I did is as follows:

```
/* get the order shipping zone meta data */
     
function get_shipping_zone(){
        
    global $woocommerce;
    $customer = new WC_Customer();
    $post_code = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_postcode();
    $zone_postcode = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_postcode();
    $zone_city =$woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_city(); 
    $zone_state = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_state(); 

    // for debugging 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($woocommerce->customer); 
    echo "</pre>"; 
  
    //show the customer order postal code, city
    echo "The post code is ". $post_code." <br/>"; 

    # here I should add the code to return the customer shipping zone ... ? 

}
```

I found this function but it is always returns the 3rd zone I don't know why ?

```
/* getting the shipping zone based on spesific package */
    
function get_shipping_zone( $package=Array()) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $shipping_zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_matching_package($package);

    $zone=$shipping_zone->get_zone_name();

    return $zone;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You should try `WC()->session` instead of `WC()->customer`. In `WC()->session` for protected `'shipping_for_package_0'` data, you can access this data this way:

```
// Accessing to 'shipping_for_package_0' protected data
$shipping_package = WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0');

// Getting the instance of WC_Shipping_Rate object
foreach ($shipping_package['rates'] as $shipping_rate) break;

// Displaying accessing to the data in the object
echo 'Rate ID: ' . $shipping_rate->id . '<br>';
echo 'Rate Label: ' . $shipping_rate->label . '<br>';
echo 'Rate Cost: ' . $shipping_rate->cost . '<br>';
echo 'Rate Tax: ' . $shipping_rate->taxes[1] . '<br>';
echo 'Method ID: ' . $shipping_rate->method_id . '<br>';
```

There is also:

```
$chosen_shipping_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods');
```

> You can also use this code in a custom function hooked in this action hooks:
>
> - `woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping` *(for cart)*
> - `woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping` *(for checkout)*

Comment: Thank You Loic for your answer, I didn't know about the WC()->session before. Highly Appreciated.

Comment: Highly appreciated, Thumps up (y)